# angular $http.post then method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this function for loging in, but I face a problem in `$http.post` method. My sever response a 400 (bad request) to incorrect username & password but in this angular code `loginSuccess` function run every time (even with incorrect username & password) and other weird thing is that response is `undefined`, while I can see response in browser network console.

```
function login (data) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.post('api/authentication/login', data)
        .then(loginSuccess, loginFailed);
//        .success(loginSuccess);

      return deferred.promise;

      function loginSuccess (response) {
        console.log(response); // <-- undefinde
        deferred.resolve();
      }

      function loginFailed () {
        deferred.reject();
      }

    }
```

But when I use `success` method (which is deprecated), there is no problem and login success doesn't run when response is error.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a **[plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/)**?

Comment: how to simulate server response in plunkr ?

Comment: Why do you use $http.post if you want to create a get request?

Comment: It was a typo mistake , fixed.

Comment: How's your API constructed?

Comment: Also why are you using deferred here? $http returns a promise already.

Comment: what you mean about "constructed" ? I use a nodejs app in the server side  that response to this request.

Comment: @MattWay I use deferred because I do some other stuff in code , this code is simiplified version of my code.

Comment: which  version of angular you are using?

Comment: @mk72 angular v1.4.7

Comment: @SamanMohamadi You can mock a request using **[$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend)**. Here is a **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EOHIXNee88cEbNm2yRSk?p=preview)** example.

Comment: Looks like there's an interceptor.

Comment: @zeroflagL Your'r right , the prolem came from an interceptor .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zeroflagL mentionded the problem was from an interceptor.
I have forgotten to return response in onResponseError.